# Error Importing flat files into Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio 18 -- "System Out of Memory"

Tags: sql-server

I have an approximately 10 GB Excel CSV that I am trying to import into a SQL Database. When I use the import flat file option / wizard the file starts to import for about 10-15 seconds before running into a System Out of Memory Exception Error. The follow is the error output and screenshots.

Any information is greatly appreciated!

```
Detailed Error Output:
Error inserting data into table. (Microsoft.SqlServer.Import.Wizard)

------------------------------
Program Location:

   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Import.Wizard.InsertData.ResultCheck(Result result)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Import.Wizard.InsertData.DoWork()
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.TaskForms.SimpleWorkItem.Run()

===================================

Error inserting data into table. (Microsoft.SqlServer.Prose.Import.SDS)

------------------------------
Program Location:

   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Prose.Import.BcpTextSynthesis.InsertIntoDB(String inputFilePath, String tableName, String schemaName, IReadOnlyList`1 columnInfo, SqlConnection connection, Int32 batchSize, SqlTransaction transaction, IList`1 allFinalTransformations, IList`1 allFinalTransformationColumns, IList`1 allFinalColNames)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Prose.Import.BcpProcess.CreateTableAndInsertDataIntoDb(String connectionString, Int32 batchSize, String azureAccessToken)

===================================

Exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' was thrown. (mscorlib)

------------------------------
Program Location:

   at System.Text.StringBuilder.ToString()
   at Microsoft.ProgramSynthesis.Read.FlatFile.Semantics.Semantics.<SplitLines>d__17.MoveNext()
   at Microsoft.ProgramSynthesis.Read.FlatFile.Semantics.Semantics.<Csv>d__9.MoveNext()
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.<SkipIterator>d__31`1.MoveNext()
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereEnumerableIterator`1.MoveNext()
   at System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Prose.Import.BcpTextSynthesis.InsertIntoDB(String inputFilePath, String tableName, String schemaName, IReadOnlyList`1 columnInfo, SqlConnection connection, Int32 batchSize, SqlTransaction transaction, IList`1 allFinalTransformations, IList`1 allFinalTransformationColumns, IList`1 allFinalColNames)





[Image of Import Wizard][1]


[Error Image 'System.OutOfMemoryException' was thrown][2]
```

Comment: Why did you tag `mysql` when you're using SQL-Server? Do you think they're the same thing?

Comment: Can you open the file in Excel? Excel files can get notoriously bloated - try copying the data into a new blank sheet, saving that, then importing. Also try saving from Excel as a csv text file and importing that.

Comment: @Stu "Excel CSV" files are still CSV files (i.e. they're _not_ bloated). Excel CSV files are the same as MySQL-style CSV files, but just an alternative escape syntax (i.e. double-double-quotes instead of backslashes) - so it won't affect memory usage at all.

Comment: Try using the old "legacy" Import Data Wizard. The new (post-2021) "Flat file" import wizard is still very unfinished: it crashes all the time for me too, not to mention its poor UX - and it offers _zero_ new functionality and removes too many essential configuration options - I don't know why Microsoft is making such a backward-step with SQL Server tooling...

Comment: I missed the mention of csv - I'd assumed a normal Excel file since Excel was mentioned, if it's a normal delimited text file then agreed it won't be bloated, but then Excel is also not really relevant, it's just a text file; from experience I've seen *actual* Excel files grow to gigabytes with data that requires just a few kilobytes!

Comment: Divide the file into smaller chunks. How small? Experiment.

Answer (score 2):

I used the Bulk insert command as per below and please make sure that the files to be load is on the SQL server and not on your local/remote machine.

```
BULK INSERT dbo.TABLE
 FROM 'E:\YOUR_FILES.csv'
WITH ( FORMAT = 'CSV',
 FIELDTERMINATOR = ',',
   ROWTERMINATOR = '\n' );
```

Comment: Also if you don't have an existing table then use the data import wizard first so it creates the table for you then use the above command to insert the data. This saves manually creating the table by hand.

Answer (score 1):

For large files like that, look into using [Bulk Insert](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/bulk-insert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16).

Comment: Note that you must be running SQL Server 2017 or later and a high compatibility-level DB to use CSV files with `BULK INSERT` and the CSV file must be accessible to the SQL Server instance either in its local filesystem or through a UNC network share (don't forget NTFS+SMB permissions!). Also, Excel will skip the quote delimiters in many cases so users might still need to _massage_ Excel's exported CSV files to play-nice with SQL Server. Also don't forget pain caused by leading `'`, `+`, and `=` chars in CSV text values that Excel "conveniently" hides...